# Trying to bulk upload to django-rest-framework (ModelViewSets) using django.client

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload multiple elements at once, using this test:

```
def test_rest_api_post_list_of_article(self):
    password = "test"
    admin = User.objects.create_superuser("test", "asdf@asdf.com", password)
    admin.save()
    client = Client()
    client.login(username=admin.username, password=password)
    response = client.post('/api/v1/artcle/', data=[{'artnr': '0001'}, {'artnr': '0002'}])
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
    artikel = Article.objects.all()
    self.assertEqual(len(article), 2)
```

but it fails with an AttributeError, do I have to wrap the list in a dict, to be able to post it? When using tastypie lists in bulk uploads where wrapped in a dict named "objects", but this does not work for DjangoRestFramework.

Is bulk uploading/updating possible with DjangoRestFramework, when using ModelViewSets?

For completeness sake, here my ViewSet:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Article
```

I just learned, that ModelViewSets don't offer bulk uploads by default :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Bulk uploading is possible in django rest framework.

You can use Django REST Framework Bulk.

"pip install djangorestframework-bulk"

import BulkModelViewSet by from rest_framework_bulk import BulkModelViewSet

and use BulkModelViewSet instead of ModelViewSet

from rest_framework_bulk import (

```
BulkListSerializer,
BulkSerializerMixin,
ListBulkCreateUpdateDestroyAPIView,
```

)

class FooSerializer(BulkSerializerMixin, ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta(object):
    model = FooModel
    # only necessary in DRF3
    list_serializer_class = BulkListSerializer
```

for more detail visit.

https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk